# mdadm won't update or install after file conflict: "Unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/mdadm;65da9dab", "no such file or directory "

Tags: rpm, opensuse, dnf, zypper

I'm trying to update my system with `zypper dup` but `mdadm` specifically is having trouble. I'm on openSUSE Tumbleweed and running this in `fish`, if that matters. I also do not have any form of RAID set up at all and I'm not really sure what `mdadm` does on the system other than handle RAID arrays, everything lives on a single drive right now.

The output I'm concerned about:

```
Checking for file conflicts: ........................................................[error]
Detected 1 file conflict:

File /sbin/mdadm
  from install of
     mdadm-4.2-150500.4.4.x86_64 (SUSE:SLE-15:Update)
  conflicts with file
     /usr/sbin/mdadm
  from install of
     mdadm-4.2-150500.4.4.x86_64 (SUSE:SLE-15:Update)

File conflicts happen when two packages attempt to install files with the same name but different contents. If you continue, conflicting files will be replaced losing the previous content.
Continue? [yes/no] (no): y

error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/mdadm;65da9dab: cpio: open failed - No such file or directory
```

I tried updating with `dnf update`, and had similar results. I also tried flat-out uninstalling `mdadm` and reinstalling even though I'm pretty sure that shouldn't do anything, and it indeed did nothing, and in hindsight that seems like a pretty bad idea because some other packages[†] in my system depend on it.

[This issue](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2273) on the `rpm` GitHub repo seems to be the same, but no fixes for the issue were posted and it doesn't seem to have gotten attention.

I feel I can safely assume that `/usr/sbin/mdadm;65da9dab` is not actually the correct directory considering the `;` in the filename. I believe the intended location is `/usr/sbin/mdadm`, since that is a file that exists, but I don't know how I would try to guide RPM to that location, if that is even the right solution. The file conflict happens consistently, but I have no idea how to resolve that "correctly" if there is a way.

†: `zypper` removed these packages when removing mdadm: `discover-backend-fwupd fwupd fwupd-bash-completion fwupd-fish-completion libbd_mdraid3 libfwupd2 typelib-1_0-Fwupd-2_0 udisks2 udisks2-bash-completion`